# Postgres: Return zero as default for rows where there is no matach

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, join

I am trying to get all the paid contracts from my contracts table and group them by month. I can get the data but for months where there is no new paid contract I want to get a zero instead of missing month. I have tried **coalesce** and **generate_series** but I cannot seem to get the missing row.

Here is my query:

```
 with months as (   
       select generate_series(
        '2019-01-01', current_date, interval '1 month'   
) as series )
    select date(months.series) as day, SUM(contracts.price) from months 
left JOIN contracts on date(date_trunc('month', contracts.to)) = months.series 
where contracts.tier='paid' and contracts.trial=false and (contracts.to is not NULL)  group by day;
```

I want the results to look like:

```
|Contract Value| Month|
| 20           | 01-2020|
| 10           | 02-2020|
| 0            | 03-2020|
```

I can get the rows where there is a contract but cannot get the zero row.

Postgres Version 10.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you want:

```
with months as (   
       select generate_series('2019-01-01', current_date, interval '1 month'   ) as series 
)
select m.series as day, coalesce(sum(c.price), 0) sum_price
from months m
left join contracts c
    on  c.to >= m.series 
    and c.to <  m.series  + interval '1' month
    and co.tier = 'paid' 
    and not c.trial
group by m.series;
```

That is:

- you want the condition on the `left join`ed table in the `on` clause of the join rather than in the `where` clause, otherwise they become mandatory, and evict rows where the `left join` came back empty
- the filter on the date can be optimized to avoid using date functions; this makes the query SARGeable, ie the database may take advantage of an index on the date column
- table aliases make the query easier to read and write

Comment: your suggestion worked for above problem but if I add *lateral* I am again stuck with the same problem:

select COALESCE(count(contracts.id),0) as trial_converted, to_char(series,'YYYY-mm') as start_at  
from generate_series('2019-01-01', current_date, interval '1 month') as series
left join contracts on contracts.from >= series and contracts.from ......
lateral (select c.id from contracts as c where c.tier='gold' and (c.to>= series or c.to is NULL) and c.account_id=contracts.account_id and c.trial=False) as sub group by start_at order by start_at desc ;

Answer (score 1):

You need to move conditions to the `on` clause:

```
with months as (   
     select generate_series( '2019-01-01'::date, current_date, interval '1 month') as series
    )
select dm.series as day, coalesce(sum(c.price), 0)
from months m left join
     contracts c
     on c.to >= m.series and
        c.to < m.series + interval '1 month' and
        c.tier = 'paid' and
        c.trial = false
group by day;
```

Note some changes to the query:

- The conditions on `c` that were in the `where` clause are in the `on` clause.
- The date comparison uses simple data comparisons, rather than truncating to the month.  This helps the optimizer and makes it easier to use an index.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- There is no need to convert `day` to a date.  It already is.
- `to` is a bad choice for a column name because it is reserved. However, I did not change it.

Comment: your suggestion worked for above problem but if I add lateral I am again stuck with the same problem: select COALESCE(count(contracts.id),0) as trial_converted, to_char(series,'YYYY-mm') as start_at from generate_series('2019-01-01', current_date, interval '1 month') as series left join contracts on contracts.from >= series and contracts.from ...... lateral (select c.id from contracts as c where c.tier='gold' and (c.to>= series or c.to is NULL) and c.account_id=contracts.account_id and c.trial=False) as sub group by start_at order by start_at desc ;

Comment: @Umer . . . I don't follow your comment.  First, you seem to be complaining about this answer, but you accepted GMB's equivalent answer.  Second, there is no `lateral join` neither in this answer nor in your question.  Perhaps you need to ask a *new* question?